# Default value for Mongoid Hash field accessor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hashmap, mongoid, activesupport

Given a Mongoid model:

```
class Counts
  include Mongoid::Document

  # lists of tag counts
  field :tags, type: Hash, default: {}
end

c = Counts.new( tags = {new: 12, old: 7})
```

I would like to override `c#tags[]` so that if a key isn't set on the `tags` field, it should return a default of `0` instead of `nil` like this:

```
c.tags['ancient']
# => 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting default hash values as below:

```
class Counts
  ...
  field :tags, type: Hash, default: Hash.new{ |h, k| h[k] = 0 }
end
```

Comment: Interesting, but this will only set the default value when none is saved (ie. when the DB field is still `nil`). Once one value is set, all other values will be back to nil. I was thinking of defining a hash accessor on the `tags` field like `def tags[](key)`, but it looks like I may have to inherit the hash class to make such a change